# Why I got java.lang.nullpointerexception in elasticsearch build node?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, build, nullpointerexception, nodes

I've test my apps using elasticsearch with very simple line of code. Like this :

```
Node node = nodeBuilder()
        .settings(Settings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").put("clster.transport.sniff", true).put("path.home", "/home/kenny/Program/Java/elastic"$
        .node();
```

But I got error like this :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:113)
at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.randomNodeName(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:198)
at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.finalizeSettings(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:177)
at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:101)
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:128)
at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:145)
at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.node(NodeBuilder.java:152)
at TryElastic.main(TryElastic.java:56)
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, I've try and looking for the solution. Line 56 at error log, refer to ".node()" method above. So, dou you have suggestion or there are something that I've to add in my code

Thanks.....

Comment: /home/kenny/Program/Java/elastic"$ probably you didn't close the parenthesis

Comment: `clster.transport.sniff` is also wrong. Do you mean `client.transport.sniff`?

Answer (score 1):

The only way this can happen is due to a misconfiguration of `path.home`.

When Elasticsearch tries to generate a random node name for your instance, it [looks for a file](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/node/internal/InternalSettingsPreparer.java#L182) at `{path.home}/config/names.txt`

If the file cannot be found, you'll get a (rather unfriendly and unhelpful) `NullPointerException`.

So the solution is to check that "/home/kenny/Program/Java/elastic" is really the top-level of an ES installation.

See here for docs on the [correct directory layout](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-dir-layout.html).

Comment: This answer saved my day. Especially when you say that ES will look at names.txt. I simply gave a node name and the issue vanished. Thank you !